# lists in structs in F#?

Tags: list, data-structures, f#, struct

I'm very new to F# and I'm trying to make a struct for storing polygons, and it has to contain a list of coordinates:

```
type Polygon =
    struct
        val Coords : list
        new(list_of_Coords) = { Coords = list_of_Coords }
    end
```

but Visual studio says "The type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.list<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 0"

I think not as I don't intend to initialise the list in the struct - just declare it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/11377.aspx

for the answer.

(Repeated here:

You need to specify the type of list, e.g. list<float>.

```
type Polygon =
    struct
        val Coords : list<float>
        new(list_of_Coords) = { Coords = list_of_Coords }
    end
```

)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Brian's anwer:
You can also make the structure generic when you don't know the type of your coordinates in advance (even if `string Polygon` wouldn't make much sense)

```
type 'a Polygon =
    struct
        val Coords : 'a list
        new(list_of_Coords) = { Coords = list_of_Coords }
    end
```

Generally, you can declare a record type like this (assume you have a `Coord` type)

```
type Polygon = { Coords : Coord list }

// Code ...

let myPolygon = { Coords = [ ... ] }
```

Comment: Regarding the "let myPolygon = { Coords = [ ... ] }" syntax:
Can I then enter something like this:
"let myPolygon = { Coords = [ [1.,2.] , [3.,4.] ] }"
or do I have to define all my Coords first? (I guess the latter as I failed doing the former)

Comment: The structure is immutable, you'll have to specify all coords in the initialization => `let myPolygon = { Coords = [ (1., 2.); (3., 4.) ] }`

Answer (score 0):

For case you want generate as float as int and other type polygons, you can use following code:

```
type Polygon<'a> =
    struct
        val Coords : list <'a>
        new(list_of_Coords) = { Coords = list_of_Coords }
    end

let inline genPolygon (a: 'a list) =
  new Polygon<'a> (a)

> genPolygon [1;2;3];;
val it : Polygon<int> = FSI_0002+Polygon`1[System.Int32] {Coords = [1; 2; 3];}
> genPolygon [1.0;2.0;3.0];;
val it : Polygon<float>
= FSI_0002+Polygon`1[System.Double] {Coords = [1.0; 2.0; 3.0];}
```

Comment: The effect of "
let inline genPolygon (a: 'a list) =
  new Polygon<'a> (a)
"
is just to avoid having to use the constructor from the Polygon type directly?

I'm more interested in being able to make a polygon without having to explicitly declare all it's corners first. I.e. write something like:
let myPolygon = { Coords = [ [1.,2.] , [3.,4.] ] }

Comment: Yes, i suppose, people prefer to use "genPoly [1;2;3]" over "new Polygon<int> [1;2;3]". It seems you want to use classic ML types, not structs. I don't know how to format comments, so please see next answer:

Answer (score 0):

```
> type 'a F = { coords: 'a list };;

type 'a F =
  {coords: 'a list;}

> let dd = {coords=[1.;2.]};;

val dd : float F

> let dd = {coords=[[1.;2.];[1.;2.]]};;

val dd : float list F
```

Comment: And if I want to ensure that polygons only use floats why can't I write this:

type HeightCurve = { coords: list<float> };;
let myHeightCurve = {coords=[[1.;2.];[1.;2.]]};;

Comment: You can, of course. Just use "type HeightCurve = { coords: float list list}" for your case.